# std::transform - std::execution::par_unseq has no effect

Tags: c++, gcc, parallel-processing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <execution>
#include <chrono>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

static auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// Start the timer
void tick() {
    
    start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

// Stop the timer and output the elapsed time in milliseconds
void tock() {
    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << duration_ms << " ms" << std::endl;
}

double compute_p_n(double m, int n) {
    return 0.5 * (1 - std::pow(1 - 2 * m, n));
}

void do_work(auto pol)
{
    const double m = 1e-2;
    const int k = 3e8; 
    std::vector<double> input(k);
    std::vector<double> results(k);

    tick();
    std::iota(input.begin(), input.end(), 1); // initialize with 1, 2, 3, ..., k
    cout << "initializing with indices: ";
    tock(); 
    
    tick();
    std::transform(pol, input.begin(), input.end(), results.begin(),
                   [m](double n) { return compute_p_n(m, n); }); // compute p(n)
    cout << "transform: "; 
    tock();
    
}

int main() {
    
    cout << "hw concur: " << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << endl;

    cout << "parallel: " << endl;
    do_work(std::execution::par_unseq);
    
    cout << endl << "sequential: " << endl;
    do_work(std::execution::seq);


    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, `std::execution::par_unseq` makes no difference; it takes 18 seconds to run `transform()`.

> g++ compute_prob.cpp --std=c++20 && ./a.out
>
> hw concur: 16
>
> parallel:
>
> initializing with indices: Elapsed time: 1389 ms
>
> transform: Elapsed time: 5303 ms
>
> sequential:
>
> initializing with indices: Elapsed time: 1366 ms
>
> transform: Elapsed time: 6576 ms

**QUESTION**
How do I make it actually use all my cores?

Comment: What compiler and platform? And how do you compile the program? They don't all implement parallelization out-of-the-box.

Comment: With mscv this seems to work as intended, but you seem to underestimate the time vector initialization and `std::iota` takes. The behaviour of the program for me is 1: slow non-parallelized iota and then the cpu usage goes to somewhere between 50 and 80 % during the transform.

Comment: Bwt: Going with `std::malloc` to avoid unnecessary initializations `std::vector<double>` would do seems to provide a good speedup. Probably it doesn't help the performance on most machines that you're using 16GB of memory for the the collections alone...

Comment: How did you benchmark the speed/run-time?

Comment: @fabian I measured `transform()` separately from allocation.

Comment: 18sec for 3M iterations is a bit too high, even for sequential exec. If you're on an embedded platform, check if `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()>1`. Because otherwise you cannot actually benefit from parallel execution. You'll need `<thread>` for that check.

Comment: @Red.Wave it's 300M and I updated with `hardware_concurrency()`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. 300M I meant. The pipelining should've sped things up.

Comment: I missed the output. 6sec for sequential exec makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was `TBB`.

I needed to install `libtbb-dev` **and** I need to pass `-ltbb` to the compiler.

Now my results are:

```
$ g++ compute_prob.cpp --std=c++20 -ltbb && ./a.out
hw concur: 16
parallel:
initializing with indices: Elapsed time: 1408 ms
transform: Elapsed time: 666 ms

sequential:
initializing with indices: Elapsed time: 1448 ms
transform: Elapsed time: 6156 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know